# Php add to array without overrides existing value?

Tags: php

I have a simple shopping cart array. I can add in the Id fine. However each time I go to submit the form it overrides the existing value?
What is the best way to stop this from happening? Below is an example of when the form is submitted

```
session_start();
$id = filter_var($_POST['Phone-ID'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$Phone_Title = filter_var($_POST['Phone-title'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$Phone_Price = filter_var($_POST['Phone-price'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$Phone_Quantity = filter_var($_POST['quantity'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);



$_SESSION['cart']['Id'] = array();


$_SESSION['cart']['Id'] = $id;
var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove this line `$_SESSION['cart']['Id'] = array();` (As it's recreate the empty array again and again)

You need to assign values to the array with new-index every-time. So do like this:-

```
$_SESSION['cart']['Id'][] = $id;
```

Note:- with your code it always over-writes the 0th index `id` presented in  `$_SESSION['cart']['Id']` array

Comment: I still seem to get a dump of one item when executed?

Comment: remove this line `$_SESSION['cart']['Id'] = array();` and check